# Expression to workout in percentages - SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I need to work out the total in percentages:

[image]

Please feel free to ask me for anymore details.

`=Sum(Fields!OutSLA.Value, "SLAPriority")/Sum(Fields!InSLA.Value, "SLAPriority")*100` I had this but didn't quite go to plan. Very basic knowledge of this sorry

**Sorry to post on this one again.. I'm getting weird percentages. i.e. -200 or -Infinity:**

[image]

Comment: what numbers are you using to get the precentages?

Comment: i.e.  from 13 to 12 = 7%
or from 105 to 0 = 100%
Does this help?

Comment: what verison of sql are you using? (mysql, sqlserver, etc.)

Comment: Microsoft 2008 R2 within SSRS (Report Manager)

Comment: So you want a sql statement to return the percentages correct?

Comment: How does 13 to 12 make 7%? Can you explain?

Comment: Yes please, or possibly just in an expression to add to the end of table

Comment: @Charleh (1-(12/13))*100 = 7%. They are really the difference of 100%

Comment: Sorry was rounding down, but I mean like   12/13 x 100/1 =1200/13   ie. 1200 divided by 13 is around 92.3076..

Comment: But would like it to display how I had it on the image

Comment: Check the updated answer. It will have all 4 columns now. I do not know your table sturcturs so just replace my column names with the ones you want to display.

Comment: @Billo, I forgot to cut off the trailing decimals before the varchar conversion.  I have updated my answer.

Comment: @ObieMD5 I added a comment below

Comment: The red highlighter makes it hard to read, can you remove it?

Comment: Red highlighter is just names

Comment: Sorry to post on this one again.. (see link to a print screen) I'm getting weird percentages. i.e. -200 or -Infinity http://i.stack.imgur.com/9Yvts.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this at the report level, you can just use something like:

```
=1 - (Fields!OutSLA.Value / Fields!InSLA.Value)
```

I wouldn't multiply by 100 in the expression, I would just set the textbox **Format** property to the approriate value, e.g. **P0**.

[image]

The above expression assumes a detail row. To apply at the in a header or footer row, you would use something like:

```
=1 - (Sum(Fields!OutSLA.Value) / Sum(Fields!InSLA.Value))
```

I tried out the first formula in a basic report:

[image]

[image]

The results are slightly different from your example, but you can see the underlying figures in the last column and why they are rounded in the P0 column.

**Edit after comment**

You can prevent Infinity values by using an IIf statements to check for *0* InSLA totals, like:

```
=1 -(IIf(Sum(Fields!InSLA.Value) <> 0
  , Sum(Fields!OutSLA.Value) / Sum(Fields!InSLA.Value)
  , 0))
```

-200% is the correct value for that particular row based on your calculation: **1 - (3/1) = -2 = -200 %.** What would you expect it to be?

Comment: Sorry to post on this one again.. (see link to a print screen)
I'm getting weird percentages. i.e. -200 or -Infinity

http://i.stack.imgur.com/9Yvts.png

Comment: I've made a few updates... Hopefully this helps! It's getting a bit further away from the original question; you might want to consider creating a new question if there are further issues.

Comment: yeah thought it might have been a new question sorry about that.
I guess I just wanted it to display 0 instead of -...%

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with convert or with Cast

Convert:

```
Select
AssignedTo,
INSLA,
OUTSLA, 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), CAST(((1-(OUTSLA/INSLA))*100) as int))+ '%' as Percentage
FROM SLATABLE
```

Cast:

```
Select 
AssignedTo,
INSLA,
OUTSLA, 
CAST(CAST((1-(OUTSLA/INSLA))*100 as int) AS VARCHAR(50))+ '%' as Percentage
FROM SLATABLE
```

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/46pGs.png  -  Here's my current coding.
Also I was actually trying to add this as an expression in the table

Comment: I did not realize that you were needing to write an expression.  That requires you to write it in .NET (says VB but probably any) not SQL.  Here is the link to it [Expressions for SRSS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328.aspx)

Comment: `=Sum(Fields!OutSLA.Value, "SLAPriority")/Sum(Fields!InSLA.Value, "SLAPriority")*100`  I had this but didn't quite go to plan.  Very basic knowledge of this sorry